# How to create spacing between items in a SwiftUI List view?

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui

I can't seem to find a way to create spacing between `List` items.
Maybe I shouldn't put in a list in the first place?

[image]

What do you think?

This the code that generates the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var ratesVM = RatesViewModel()
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "midnight blue")
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List (ratesVM.ratesList, id: \.self) { rate in
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    
                    Button(action: {print("pressed")}) {
                        Text(rate.hebrewCurrencyName)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("המרות מטבע")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: {
                    print("button pressed")
                    self.ratesVM.callService()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)})
        }.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/divider

Comment: @JawadAli answer seems to be the correct way to do this actually this from Hacking with swift. Here is the link it contains a video explanation https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-spacing-around-individual-views-using-padding

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define the minimum list row height to be bigger so you'll have more separation between rows.

```
List (ratesVM.ratesList, id: \.self) { rate in
       Image(systemName: "plus")
       Button(action: {print("pressed")}) {
                    Text(rate.hebrewCurrencyName)
       }
}.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 50) //minimum row height
```

Alternatively you can build your row as a HStack and specify a frame height.

```
List (ratesVM.ratesList, id: \.self) { rate in
    HStack {
       Image(systemName: "plus")
       Button(action: {print("pressed")}) {
          Text(rate.hebrewCurrencyName)
       }
    }.frame(height: 50) //your row height 
}.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 20)
```

Or as a VStack and and use Spacers

```
List (ratesVM.ratesList, id: \.self) { rate in
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        HStack {
           Image(systemName: "plus")
           Button(action: {print("pressed")}) {
              Text(rate.hebrewCurrencyName)
           }
        }
        Spacer()
    }.frame(height: 50)
}.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 20)
```

Comment: Not working if you want to remove spacing. This only sets a minimum height of the cell but does not adjust the space between them.

Comment: I don't see why this is an accepted answer as it doesn't answer the original question at all. The question is about space between rows, the answer is about rows height.

Answer (score 11):

### The SwiftUI way

You can achieve it by removing the list row separators `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` and setting the list row background to an InsettableShape `.listRowBackground()` defining top and bottom EdgeInsets padding. Btw, don't forget to set the `.listStyle(.plain)` to `.plain`.

You can find a better implementation on this dev post [SwiftUI List Card View](https://dev.to/kafran/swiftui-list-card-view-2da4).

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  My App
//
//  Created by Kolmar Kafran on 25/08/22.
//  https://www.linkedin.com/in/kolmar-kafran/
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(someList, id: \.self) { n in
                Text("\(n)")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .listRowBackground(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .background(.clear)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .padding(
                                EdgeInsets(
                                    top: 2,
                                    leading: 10,
                                    bottom: 2,
                                    trailing: 10
                                )
                            )
                    )
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .onDelete { idx in
                someList.remove(atOffsets: idx)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very good solution and it uses all standard SwiftUI components, no hacking, lol.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I needed to add the following to my `Section`:

```swift
List {
    Section {
        ForEach(nearbyLocations, id: \.id) { location in
            LocationCard(location: location)
        }
    }
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.listRowBackground(Color.clear)
.listRowSpacing(10)
```

To change the spacing of the cards, update the `listRowSpacing` as needed.

Posting this here incase someone needs a similar result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

padding didn't work since it only increased the size of the item/cell and not the spacing between, but
**.environment(.defaultMinListRowHeight, 20)** 
seemed to work

I also implemented a custom view for the button styling to adjust the frame and "pressable area" of the button relative to the item/cell.

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
            .frame(width: 350, height: 50, alignment: Alignment.center)
            .background(Color.orange)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var ratesVM = RatesViewModel()

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "midnight blue")
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List (ratesVM.ratesList, id: \.self) { rate in
                Button(action: {print("pressed")}) {
                    Text(rate.hebrewCurrencyName)
                }.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("המרות מטבע")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: {
                    print("button pressed")
                    self.ratesVM.callService()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)})
        }.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
            .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 150)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI lets us set individual padding around views using the padding() modifier. If you use this with no parameters you’ll get system-default padding on all sides, like this:

```
VStack {
    Text("SwiftUI")
        .padding()
    Text("rocks")
}
```

But you can also customize how much padding to apply and where. So, you might want to apply system padding to only one side:

```
Text("SwiftUI")
    .padding(.bottom)
```

Or you might want to control how much padding is applied to all sides:

```
Text("SwiftUI")
    .padding(100)
```

Or you can combine the two to add a specific amount of padding to one side of the view:

```
Text("SwiftUI")
    .padding(.bottom, 100)
```

so you can do

```
Text(rate.hebrewCurrencyName)
      .padding(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution here is to just set the corresponding `listStyle` to [`SidebarListStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sidebarliststyle). For instance:

```
List {
    Text("First row")
    Text("Second row")
    Text("Third row")
}
.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
```

But please note that on macOS and iOS, the sidebar list style also displays disclosure indicators in the section headers that allow the user to collapse and expand sections.

Another quick alternative would be to use the [`Divider()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/divider) helper view instead (i.e., a visual element that can be used to separate other content):

```
List {
    Text("First row")
    Divider()
    Text("Second row")
    Divider()
    Text("Third row")
}
```

Both solutions won't allow direct control of the vertical spacing but at least provides a more spacious layout alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
struct AuthView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    let t = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        List(t, id: \.self){ item in
                HStack{
                    Text(item)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 40, height: 39, alignment: .center)
                .padding(10)
                .background(Color("AppRecommended"))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

}

Note: .listRowSeparator(.hidden) works for iOS 15 and above